# How can we configure the cpu and memory resources for Jupyter notebook

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I am new to using Jupyter notebook. I have installed Jupyter using Anaconda and have set up a jupyter server. I wanted to control the cpu and memory available for Jupyter. Is there any configuration for doing that? What is the best way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: There's no native config no - since a Jupyter server is usually assumed to be run by a trusted user it makes no sense to limit the resources available to it. If you do want to though - you might consider external ways of managing CPU/memory - I can suggest Docker as a good start as Docker allows for setting resource limits on its containers and a lto of the Jupyter community (via Jupyterhub) are familiar with Docker.

Comment: Huh. I trust myself to make mistakes and use too much memory in my notebooks, so I guess I'll have to fire up some ulimit commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify CPU limit to Jupyter notebook process using

```
sudo cpulimit -l 100 -p <PID>
```

where PID is ID of your process, -l is for limit, you can read man page  to learn how to use it.